# Uncaught TypeError: x.replace is not a function. Didnt get before this change

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, typeerror

I use this following lines for changing the value from some variables taken from user input.
This allow me change the `,` for `.` (Neccesary for operations with float).

`va`,`vcc` and `consumo` are the variables.

```
consumo = consumo.replace(",",".");
va = va.replace(",",".");
vcc = vcc.replace(",",".");
```

Then I decided to make a function, for saving lines codes, so I created this:

```
function comaAPunto(n1,n2,n3){
   n1 = n1.replace(",",".");
   n2 = n2.replace(",",".");
   n3 = n3.replace(",",".");    
}
```

And the code now looks like
`comaAPunto(consumo,va,vcc);`

But now, I got this error when I run code.

> Uncaught TypeError: n1.replace is not a function

Do you know why? When is inside a function dont work, but outside it, it works.

As request, I post full code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


        var vcc;
        var va;
        var consumo;
        var r1;
        var r2;
        $('#calcular').click(calcularvalores);
        /*Para seleccionar todos los text box*/

        function seleccionar(){
            this.select();
        }


        $('#consumo').click(seleccionar); //Select all text
        $('#vcc').click(seleccionar);
        $('#a').click(seleccionar);
        $('#consumo').keyup(calcularvalores); // WHen user change value
        $('#vcc').keyup(calcularvalores);
        $('#a').keyup(calcularvalores);


        function getvalores(){ //Take what user types
        vcc = document.getElementById("vcc").value;
        va = document.getElementById("a").value;
        consumo = document.getElementById("consumo").value;
        }

        function valores(){ // Parse it to float
        vcc = parseFloat(vcc);
        va = parseFloat(va);
        consumo = parseFloat(consumo);
        }
        function verificar(checkthis){ //Check if stil NaN
            if (isNaN(checkthis)){
                return false;
            } else{ 
                return true;
            }
        }
        function comaAPunto(t1,t2,t3){ // Change , to .
            t1 = t1.replace(",",".");
            t2 = t2.replace(",",".");
            t3 = t3.replace(",",".");


        }

        function calcularvalores(){
            getvalores(); // Get user input

            comaAPunto(va,vcc,consumo); // <-- Error here tryng to change "," to "."

            valores(); // Parsing values to float.
            /* Ecuations implemented */
            consumo = consumo/1000; //Lo convertimos en mA.
            r2 = va/consumo;
            r1 = (vcc-va)/consumo;
            /* FInish ecuations */
            var isok = verificar(va); //Look if user didnt leave it blank or with text inside it.
            if(isok){
            var isreally = verificar(consumo); //Look if fill blank another space.
            if(isreally){
            $('#r11').html("<p>"+r1+"</p>"); //Print values if okay
            $('#r22').html("<p>"+r2+"</p>");
        } else{
            $('#r11').html("<p>Ingresa corriente</p>");
            $('#r22').html("<p>Ingresa corriente</p>");
        }
        } else{
            $('#r11').html("<p>Calculando</p>");
            $('#r22').html("<p>Calculando</p>");
        }
        }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Sounds like whatever youre passing into comaAPunto's n1 is null or undefined, or isnt actually a string. Try n1.toString().replace?

Comment: can you post your actual code?

Comment: Additionally `n1 = n1.replace(...)` does not set the variable outside the function, it only assigns to the function's local variable.

Comment: Is this typescript? If so you need to define the types on your parameters as strings. Ie function comaAPunto(n1: string, n2: string, n3:string)

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to show your actual current code, since you tagged it as Javascript but now in comments show a different code and says it is typescript. [mcve] and [ask] are good reads too

Comment: @Addis Updated. Thank you

Comment: @CalvinNunes Got confussed, its not typescript. I got typerror. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: @cubrr could you please show and example for changing the actual variable ussing is as parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop calling the `calcularvalores` function on every `keyup` event. In doing so you are calling the function before all three input fields have values, so empty string `''` will passed from the other input fields.

EDIT: In case you need to use `keyup` event on the input fields, make sure all the fields have valid value before executing the function. I have added `if(consumo.length === 0 || vcc.length === 0 || va.length === 0)   return;` for this purpose.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){


        var vcc;
        var va;
        var consumo;
        var r1;
        var r2;
        $('#calcular').click(calcularvalores);
        /*Para seleccionar todos los text box*/

        function seleccionar(){
            this.select();
        }


        $('#consumo').click(seleccionar); //Select all text
        $('#vcc').click(seleccionar);
        $('#a').click(seleccionar);
        $('#consumo').keyup(calcularvalores); // WHen user change value
        $('#vcc').keyup(calcularvalores);
        $('#a').keyup(calcularvalores);


        function getvalores(){ //Take what user types
            vcc = document.getElementById("vcc").value;
            va = document.getElementById("a").value;
            consumo = document.getElementById("consumo").value;
        }

        function valores(){ // Parse it to float
            vcc = parseFloat(vcc);
            va = parseFloat(va);
            consumo = parseFloat(consumo);
        }
        function verificar(checkthis){ //Check if stil NaN
            if (isNaN(checkthis)){
                return false;
            } else{ 
                return true;
            }
        }
        function comaAPunto(t1,t2,t3){ // Change , to .
            t1 = t1.toString().replace(",",".");
            t2 = t2.toString().replace(",",".");
            t3 = t3.toString().replace(",",".");


        }

        function calcularvalores(){
            getvalores(); // Get user input

            if(consumo.length === 0 || vcc.length === 0 || va.length === 0)   return;

            comaAPunto(va,vcc,consumo); // <-- Error here tryng to change "," to "."

            valores(); // Parsing values to float.
            /* Ecuations implemented */
            consumo = consumo/1000; //Lo convertimos en mA.
            r2 = va/consumo;
            r1 = (vcc-va)/consumo;
            /* FInish ecuations */
            var isok = verificar(va); //Look if user didnt leave it blank or with text inside it.
            if(isok){
              var isreally = verificar(consumo); //Look if fill blank another space.
              if(isreally){
                $('#r11').html("<p>"+r1+"</p>"); //Print values if okay
                $('#r22').html("<p>"+r2+"</p>");
              } 
              else{
                  $('#r11').html("<p>Ingresa corriente</p>");
                  $('#r22').html("<p>Ingresa corriente</p>");
              }
            } 
            else{
                $('#r11').html("<p>Calculando</p>");
                $('#r22').html("<p>Calculando</p>");
            }
        }
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Hello sir, thank for your answer and your effort. 
My objetive was that the page show "real time" changes, so i found that keyup event, in that way the user shouldnt clic any button.
Here is the working code (before i create the function)
https://electronictools.000webhostapp.com/

Try putting 5, 2.5 and 1 in the user input fields, youl'll see how the values of resistor are changing every you fill the space. Then, change the second fill from 2.5 to 2,5, you will get the same value (becase i change the , to . in that lines of code) The problem apper making it a function. It didnt return...

Comment: ... NaN becase I leave defalut value on the input.

Thank you again.

Comment: By the way the default values do not matter as they get assigned on every keyup from any of the inputs.